# How to make the calculation work when X doesn't divide evenly into N

Tags: c

You are given N litres of water, and required to transport it with barrels. Each barrel would hold X litres of water. Both N and X are positive integers.
Your input consists of two positive integers N and X, and the output should be the number of barrels (M) that needed to transport the water.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int N, X, M;

    do {
        printf("Please input a positive integer\n");
        scanf("%d%d", &N, &X);    
    } while (N, X < 0);

    M = N / X;

    printf("Total amount of water:%d\n", N);
    printf("Barrel capacity:%d\n", X);
    printf("%d barrels are needed\n", M);

    return 0;
}
```

Sample run for a case that works:

```
Please input a positive integer
Total amount of water:60
Barrel capacity:5
12 barrels are needed
```

Sample run for a case that doesn't work:

```
Please input a positive integer
Total amount of water:59
Barrel capacity:5
11 barrels are needed
```

The expected output for the second run is 12, but I get 11. How do I make the calculation work when `X` doesn't divide evenly into `N`? I can't find the code that works for 59 liters.

Comment: What exactly is the issue here?  Are you saying that you input 59 and the output is 60?

Comment: Integer division works like that in a floor manner.  It will not round and it will not ceiling

Answer (score 4):

> I can't find the code that works for 59 litres.

The reason your code works for 60, 12 but not 59, 12 is that you are dividing in integers, which drops the remainder. A simple approach in this situation is to add barrel's capacity minus one to the amount of water that needs to be transported:

```
M = (N+X-1) / X;
```

This trick works, because if `N` is divisible by `X`, the result is going to remain the same as the result without addition, while in situations when `N` is not divisible by `X`, an extra `1` would be added to the result for the partial barrel.

**Note:** Loop condition does not do what you think it does: `N, X < 0`. It should be `N < 0 || X < 0`.

Comment: What about the potential overflows?

Comment: @EOF Although it is certainly true that this approach would break when the amount is close to the max value an `int` can hold, I think the problem is about teaching students the effects of integer division. If they must worry about numeric overflow, they could use 64-bit `unsigned long long`, which would be sufficient to compute the number of barrels required to transport the volume of [Baikal lake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Baikal) five hundred times.